# MacBook Pro crashes randomly after dropping it on the floor

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, kernel-panic

A few days ago my MacBook Pro slipped out of my hands and fell onto the tile floor. The outside got banged up quite a bit and the Touch Bar no longer lights up but still responds to touches sometimes but not all the time.

Anyway, since then it will randomly restart every once in a while with a kernel panic. I have the log posted below and wanted to know if anyone could tell me what is causing the panic?

[Kernel Panic Log](https://pastebin.com/RmrJREuW)

Comment: If bits change unexpectedly all bets are off.

Answer (score 3):

**You broke your MacBook, you need to take it for service.**

The symptom that your Touch bar sometimes works (a.k.a. *intermittently*) means there is a bad/shorted connection somewhere.  Without physically examining it, it's impossible to tell what.  This is something for a professional to diagnose.

Comment: Oh yeah I knew that I would need to take it in for service. I was just curious if the kernel panics were directly related to the touch bar or not. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

The failure of the touch bar is related. The kernel log says the failure is in `AppleEmbeddedOSSupport`. `AppleEmbeddedOS` is the software that on the T1 chip that runs the touch bar.

Comment: Thanks! Figured that's what it was but just wanted to confirm before I take it in for repair.